# how to add smoothly google add into the code

Tags: php, html

```
<form action="loop.php" method=post>
    <table>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2" align ="center">Wyslij komus e-mail!</td>
        <td rowspan="7">
        <google ad/>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><br/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td>Adresat:</td>
        <td align="center"><input type="text" name="adresat" /></td>
    </tr>
        <tr>
        <td>Temat: </td>
        <td align="center"><input type="text" name="temat" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Ilosc wiadomosci: </td>
        <td align="center"><input type="number" name="iloscwiadomosci" min="1" max="99"/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Tresc: </td>
        <td align="center"><input type="text" name="tresc" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2" align="center"><input type="submit" value="Wyslij!" /></td>
    </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

that's how the site look right now https://i.stack.imgur.com/xhwgR.jpg
The problem is I don't want to make the rows wider how to correct it?

Comment: You could stop using tables for layout, for once.

Comment: please don't judge me :( Someday I will now I just need help. Though what would you make site in in css table ?

Comment: Make use of form elements properly. `<form>` `<label>` `<input>`. Use CSS `display: block` to make nice lines, `float: right` or even `flexbox` to align inputs.

Answer (score 1):

You could put another table around it like this: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/XMAun/)

```
<table>
<tr>
    <td style="vertical-align:top">
        your form here          
    </td>
    <td>
        your ad here
    </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: now the ad is on the bottom but I would like to keep it on the right side

Comment: There must be something wrong with the table then, are you missing a `</td>` or `</tr>` somewhere? Mozilla Firefox' source code window will make everything red starting from where an error occurs, I'm not sure about Chrome and others.

Comment: the code is in my main post and I just added your lines at the end and in many different spots and couldn't make it to be on the right side.

Comment: I don't see it? Your main post is still the old one, can you maybe put your code on http://jsfiddle.net/?

Comment: I fixed it: http://jsfiddle.net/3Qr3b/ -- I think you misunderstood my post a bit, you just added another table row or something instead of putting the whole table into another table. This one should work. I added some "aaaaaa" lines to demonstrate that, your ad doesn't show on jsfiddle for me.

Comment: I love you it works. Although I don't really get it I didn't know you could start <table> close it </table> and after that add another row and close the table again

Comment: Well yes you can do that, it's just a table inside another table :)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/46105/discussion-between-user1781026-and-ronni-skansing)